# WPF Convert Called Once for ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, converters

I have 2 grids in my wpf application, Grid Parent, Grid Child. When user select a record in Grid Parent, Child grid shows the entries for that parent grid record. On change of each record in parent, child rebind new values that are correspondent to it. On mouse over on each row i have set a converter which either show or hide in icon in one of the column of that record.

**Issue:** When the child grid is bound for the first time, On mouseover of record it calls that converter. As soon as i change the record in parent the child grid rebind but on mouse over those records do not call converter to show are hide the icon. It remebers the last values returned by the converter.

**Required Behavior:** The behavior that is required is that the converter should call on each row mouseover.

I'm unable to paste the actual code here so i made a sample project which may solve my problem if i solve the issue in that sample.

**Note:** For Simplicity i'm pasting my whole code of sample project **you just need to create those file** in project run.

**BaseNotifyChanged.cs**

```
public class BaseNotifyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyname = "")
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }
}
```

**Model: Person.cs**

```
public class Person : BaseNotifyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set 
        {
            if (this._name != value)
            {
                this._name = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private string _email;
    public string Email
    {
        get { return _email; }
        set
        {
            if (this._email != value)
            {
                this._email = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**View Model: Employees.cs**

```
public class Employees: BaseNotifyChanged
{
    public Employees()
    {
        this.Employee = new ObservableCollection<Person>()
        {
            new Person(){ Name = "Zeb", Email = "zeb@gmail.com"},
            new Person(){ Name = "Asad", Email = "asad@gmail.com"},
            new Person(){ Name = "Javeed", Email = "javeed@gmail.com"}
        };
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _employee;

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Employee
    {
        get { return _employee; }
        set 
        {
            if (this._employee != value)
            {
                this._employee = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**View: MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <localCnr:ListToStringConverter x:Key="LtSCtr"></localCnr:ListToStringConverter>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Employee, Converter={StaticResource LtSCtr}}"/> 
        <Button Content="Add New Employee" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**View Code Behind: MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Employees employee { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        employee = new Employees();
        this.DataContext = employee;
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        employee.Employee.Add(new Person(){ Name = "New Employee", Email = "new@gmail.com"});
    }
}
```

**Converter: ListToStringConverter.cs**

```
public class ListToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Person> employess = value as ObservableCollection<Person>;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (Person person in employess)
        {
            sb.Append(person.Name + " , ");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

As per my knowledge in my orginal scenario the grid is rebinding but as the collection object it self didn't update instead a value in added or removed so it didn't call the convert. Any suggesstions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: A simple fix would be to call `employee.RaisePropertyChanged("Employee")` at the end of `ButtonBase_OnClick`

Comment: @KooKiz wawo man you are so awesome. I've spent almost 1.5 day on this issue. Kindly answer that comment so that i can mark it as answer latter on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're adding an element to the collection, you're not modifying the `Employee` property, and therefore the NotifyPropertyChanged event is not raised.
A simple fix would be to call `employee.RaisePropertyChanged("Employee")` at the end of `ButtonBase_OnClick`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to explain the above answer, since employee.Employee is an ObservableCollection, you would expect it to auto-notify the bounded TextBlock, but the TextBlock still stays unchanged when Employee list is updated.

The explanation is that the Text property is not expecting a collection, and therefore doesn't listen to CollectionChanged events. In other words, the    `ObservableCollection<Person>`, is notifying of changes, but nobody is listening to the notifications. Using KooKiz method explicitly tells the TextBlock as if the "Emplyoee" property has changed (and not just the collection behind it), to which the TextBlock is listening.